# How do I quickly navigate through xml (DI) configuration files?

Tags: visual-studio, navigation, resharper, keyboard-shortcuts, spring.net

I'm working on a .net project that uses the [Spring.NET](http://springframework.net/) framework for dependency injection (DI). A typical solution contains several dozens of (small) xml DI configuration files. Navigating through these files isn't as frictionless as it could be.

I would like to know more tricks to be able to quickly navigate through the xml object definitions and the corresponding code. Got some you care to share?

*Example scenarios*

For instance, a solution contains the following files:

```xml
<!-- file1.xml -->
<object id="exampleObject" 
        type="Examples.ExampleObject, ExamplesLibrary">
  <property name="objectOne" ref="anotherExampleObject"/>    
</object>

<!-- file2.xml, somewhere in the same solution -->
<object id="anotherExampleObject" 
        type="Examples.AnotherExampleObject, ExamplesLibrary">
  <property name="Name" value="anotherExampleObject"/>    
</object>
```

Assuming you are working in file1.xml, how would you quickly navigate from ...

- `ref="anotherExampleObject"` to the object definition in `file2.xml`?
- `type="Examples.ExampleObject, ExamplesLibrary"` to the `ExampleObject` class in `Examples.ExampleObject.cs`

*Notes*

I'm [fully aware](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6064759/spring-codeconfig-vs-xml-configuration) of the [advantages and disadvantages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033004/castle-windsor-or-spring-net-advantages-and-disadvantages) of using XML for configuring a DI container. Let's just accept the fact that I'm required to use xml and that I would like the process to be as friction-less as possible.

Answers do not have to be specific to Spring.NET, navigation tricks used for xml configuration in other .NET DI frameworks are appreciated too.

Currently I work mostly with VS 2010 with ReSharper 6; feel free to recommend any tool compatible with VS 2008 or 2010.

Comment: Why are you using configuration anyway? Configuration through code is much less fragile, and much more maintainable. The general advice is only to use xml for parts that parts of the configuration that must be changable at time of deployement.

Comment: Two reasons: 1. Spring.NET introduced "offical" configuration in code [just a short time ago](http://springframework.net/#spring-code-config-1.0.1-released) (long after we configured most of the app in xml) 2. a fairly large part of the configuration involves the configuration of hardware devices which we need to be able to change in production.

Comment: @Steven: I do agree with your comment, but it's besides the point. I've updated my question to reflect this.

Comment: @Mauricio: I intentionally left out the spring.net tag in order not to narrow this down to spring.net. In a sense, navigation issue applies to a lot of other xml configuration situations too. I'm even considering removing the DI tag - you might be able to share some "NHibernate xml navigation tricks" for instance.

Comment: @Marijn: sorry, feel free to revert my change. Still, I think this tag is useful here because Spring.net users are particularly affected by this problem so they might have insightful comments about it.

Comment: @Mauricio: I feel absolutely free to do so :-). You've got a point putting up the tag; I'll leave it there for now and will reconsider this later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a DI configuration file, ReSharper allows me to control-click in the value type attribute to immediately jump to the corresponding class:

[image: ctrl-click to cs file]

Furthermore, with the cursor at **I** I can hit "alt-`" to show the navigation menu:

[image: alt-backtick to show navigation menu]

Comment: In exchange, Resharper sucks the living hell out of your RAM/CPU.

Answer (score 0):

Not a really good one, but I find myself using "Find in solution" a lot.

With ReSharper: "Find Usages Advanced" `ctrl+shift+alt+F12`, selecting "Textual occurence" and Solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you're already using ReSharper (and don't mind using it/do not face OOM issues), then that's the best thing out there.

I find myself resorting to lighter extensions such as [PhatStudio](http://phatstudio.sourceforge.net/) or [Quick Open File](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/3eb2f230-2728-4d5f-b448-4c0b64154da7) to ***switch*** to different files.

This of course is limited by the fact that you need to be aware of the file name to switch to. If not, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> filtered by `.xml` or `[common_naming_ pattern.extension]` files does the trick.

Again, compared to ReSharper, this seems long-winded. But if you're like me who cannot live with Resharper 6 turned on (OOM exceptions are so often on my PC that I'd to disable it), then this is the best alternative.